using the G,S,R function, I keep getting a dotted line nad two arrows attached to the object. What are they and how do i get rid of them
i am very new to blender and do not know how the lines appered and hoe to get rid of the, I have tried the gizmo settings

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Unfortunately you did not add a screenshot. Without I can only guess the dotted line is the one indicating that you are using a transformation tool like move (G), scale (S) or rotate (R) connected to the pivot point and the arrows indicate that moving the mouse will increase or decrease the effect of the tool. So this is absolutely normal when using a tool... why exactly do you want to get rid of it or if you are talking about something else, please edit your question and add screenshots to it so that we know what you are talking about.

thanks for the adviced. i am new to this system and in future will include additional information.
